# How to view HP Smart Array firmware version on HP Proliant BL460c blade server

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, firmware

What is/are the quickest way(s) to view firmware version for HP Smart Array (preferably GUI version)? 
Should I look for it in Windows or it can be viewed via the iLO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the HP Management Agents installed, the `hpacucli` utility, part of the [Array Configuration Software](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/index.html) will provide all of the controller information you need. For Windows 2003, [download this package for command-line tool](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884083&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_5fb3d776fbc44823b983bd79df%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) *or* this, [for the GUI](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884083&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_46d4dda204a849d1a48685e908%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

The `ctrl all show config detail` directive will output something like:

=> ctrl all show config detail

```
Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Bus Interface: PCI           
   Slot: 0                      
   Serial Number: 50123456789ABCDE
   Cache Serial Number: PBCDF0BRHYI032
   RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
   Controller Status: OK        
   Chassis Slot:                
   Hardware Revision: Rev C     
   Firmware Version: 5.12       
   Rebuild Priority: High       
   Expand Priority: High        
   Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs  
   Queue Depth: Automatic       
   Monitor and Performance Delay: 60 min
   Elevator Sort: Enabled       
   Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled
   Inconsistency Repair Policy: Disabled
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Accelerator Ratio: 25% Read / 75% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Enabled
   Total Cache Size: 1024 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Enabled
   Cache Backup Power Source: Capacitors
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   SATA NCQ Supported: True

   Array: A
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0 MB
      Status: OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the same by clicking on storage tab (OA--->Device BAY X--->ILO---> ILO web administration page --> System overview--> Storage).

Snapshot for a quick refernce:

[image]